# Sending commands to an esc / pos network printer

Tags: escpos

Tell me please. There is an Xprinter q260 receipt printer. How can I send esc / pos commands to it using the web?
The printer is connected to ethernet.
When switching to `http://192.168.0.110:9100`, the printer prints information about the device from which they clicked on a web link.

Comment: There will be too little content to get answers and advice. Please add information such as the configuration of the system and program, and what program wants to print when and what.

Comment: I have answered a similar question recently. please refer this article. [Is there any way to print from Google Chrome to thermal printer (escpos) in local network without using apps like QZ tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59517689/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you use C++, then for this, I made a class. Here some snippets of the class to re-use:

to open a socket for the printer:

```
m_sock =socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int on =1;
if ( setsockopt( m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*) &on,
        sizeof(on)) == -1)
    return false;
```

to connect to the printer:

```
sockaddr_in m_addr;
m_addr.sin_family =AF_INET;
m_addr.sin_port =htons( port);
int status =inet_pton( AF_INET, host.c_str(), &m_addr.sin_addr);
if ( errno == EAFNOSUPPORT)
    return false;
status =::connect( m_sock, (sockaddr *) &m_addr, sizeof(m_addr));
return ( status == 0) ? true:false;
```

to print data to the printer:

```
int bytes_sent = ::send( m_sock, data, length, MSG_NOSIGNAL );
```

to close the printer after the job:

```
::close( m_sock);
```