# Is there any way to print from Google Chrome to thermal printer (escpos) in local network without using apps like QZ tray?

Tags: google-chrome, thermal-printer, escpos

Are PWA functionality (service-worker) can help or there no way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This document contains a sample program that prints easily using the socket interface in C language.
[UB-E04 Technical Reference Guide](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_doc&cid=5144&dcat=22&pcat=53)

It seems that the equivalent can be implemented using JavaScript WebSocket.
This article is available in both Japanese and English, and both provide examples of using WebSocket easily from vanilla JavaScript.
[5分で動かせるwebsocketのサンプル3つ](https://qiita.com/okumurakengo/items/a8ccea065f5659d1a1de) / [WebSocket Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYxzS__5yYQnRizvwNYWwzFjd9J4ni_Ga)
[Introducing WebSockets: Bringing Sockets to the Web](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

The following is a sample program in Linux C language described in the document.
Sending to a printer can be done with such a simple program.
The data to be sent must be created in the format described in the ESC/POS command reference.

> ```
> /* TCP9100 programming sample for LINUX
>  * HOW TO BUILD
>  * cc ltcp.c
>  */
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #include <netdb.h>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>     int sock;
>     struct sockaddr_in addr;
>     if (argc != 2) {
>         printf("usage: ltcp <ip address>\n");
>         exit(1);
>     }
>
>     /* create socket */
>     sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>     if (sock < 0) {
>         perror("socket()");
>         exit(1);
>     }
>
>     /* initialize the parameter */
>     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
>     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
>     addr.sin_port = htons(9100);
>     addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
>
>     /* connect */
>     if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
>         perror("connect()");
>     }
>     printf("connected\n");
>
>     /* send data */
>     send(sock, "EPSON UB-E04\n", 13, 0);
>
>     /* close socket */
>     close(sock);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```